# Error while connecting QPushButton::clicked signal to a slot

Tags: c++, qt

First of all, I created about 20 push buttons using for loop. And named them using if else loop. Now, I want to connect each push buttons with the new dialog box. If I had used the design mode of QT, it would show me the name of the button when I press `connect(ui->pushButton_0, SIGNAl(released()), SLOT(digit_pressed())` something like this. But, I don't know the name of the pushbutton I made as the for and if else loop made it. The `connect(ui-> .......)` also doesn't show any predictions. How can I link these push buttons and a new dialog box?

Here is my code:

## mainwindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

## mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "amputation.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->)



    QPixmap pix("/home/skanda/Desktop/D4564.png");
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(pix);
    setWindowTitle("First Aid");

    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        if(i==0){
             QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Amputation");
             lay->addWidget(button);
        }
        else if(i==1){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Asthama");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==2){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Bleeding");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==3){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Burns");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==4){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Chest Pain");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==5){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Diarrhoea");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==6){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Drowning");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==7){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Epilepsy");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==8){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Fainting");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==9){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Fever");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==10){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Food Poisoning");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==11){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Fracture");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==12){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Head Injury");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==13){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Muscle Strain");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==14){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("No breathing");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==15){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Nose bleed");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==16){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Poisoning");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==17){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Snake Bites");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==18){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Stroke");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==19) {
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Sun Burn");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==20) {
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Testicle Pain");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==21) {
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Ulcer");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==22) {
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Child delievery");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else if(i==23) {
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Heart Attack");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
        else {
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Gastric");
            lay->addWidget(button);

        }
    }


    ui->scrollContents->setLayout(lay);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    Amputation amp;
    amp.setModal(true);
    amp.show();
}
```

**In these codes, I have tried my luck by creating `on_pushButton_clicked()` function. But, it was just a try. **

Comment: I would imagine that 20 push buttons are extreme for a user interface.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : I too feel that, but it's not extreme if it's all different options for a user under a `QDialog` or something.

Comment: What is the relevance of associating the button text with the `i` ?

Answer (score 1):

As in programming everything is cooking, :), let's see what are the ingredients of `connect()`:

```
connect(sender, &Sender::signal, receiver, &Receiver::slot);
```

so sender would be the `buttons`, the signal is the `clicked`, the receiver itself, that is, `this`, and the slot `on_pushButton_clicked`

I see unnecessary if-else, everything can be reduced to a for:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "amputation.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QPixmap pix("/home/skanda/Desktop/D4564.png");
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(pix);
    setWindowTitle("First Aid");

    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout();
    QStringList names{"Amputation", "Asthama", "Bleeding", "Burns", "Chest Pain",
                      "Drowning", "Diarrhoea", "Epilepsy", "Fainting", "Fever",
                      "Food Poisoning", "Fracture", "Head Injury", "Muscle Strain",
                     "No breathing", "Nose bleed", "Poisoning", "Snake Bites",
                      "Stroke","Sun Burn", "Testicle Pain", "Ulcer", "Child delievery",
                      "Heart Attack", "Gastric"};
    for(const QString & name: names)
    {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(name);
        lay->addWidget(button);
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked)

    }
    ui->scrollContents->setLayout(lay);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    Amputation amp;
    amp.setModal(true);
    amp.show();
}
```

**Note:**

avoid using the old style of connection, has many disadvantages, read the content of the following link for more information:

- https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: Nice, really like the usage of `QStringList`. But just a question off the top of my head, how is the deletion of all these buttons handled ?

Comment: @VishaalShankar 
The wonder of Qt is that if the parent dies (he is eliminated) he will kill the children before dying, and in the case of the QPushButton to be established within a layout these will be children of the widget where the layout is stable, ie the QScrollArea, and the QScrollArea following the same logic is children of the MainWindow so if the MainWindow closes it will be removed with the current configuration, and will kill their children, and these children their own children, so the buttons will also they will be eliminated.

Comment: @VishaalShankar 
In conclusion if you delete the windows they will eliminate the widgets they have in charge.

Comment: That is true. It completely slipped my mind. Good Answer !

Answer (score 0):

1. Make all these `QPushButton` members of a class such that they are created and destroyed properly rather than creating them in an loop.
2. Once you have each one as a separate member, then have a method `InitializeConnections()` and make all the connections under it using the Qt connect syntax.

If you believe these buttons are part of the `MainWindow` class, then your class can look something like this :

```
class MainWindow{
    ...
    ...
    private :
      // Will make connections of each button to it's respective slot.
      void InitializeConnections();

    private :
      QPushButton *mAmputationButton;
      QPushButton *mAsthmaButton;
    //.. so on
};
```

And in `MainWindow.cpp` :

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
mAmputationButton(new QPushButton("Amputation") ),
mAsthmaButton(new QPushButton("Asthama") )
{
   InitializeConnections();
}

void MainWindow::InitializeConnections()
{
   connect(mAmputationButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::amputation_slot );
   connect(mAsthmaButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::asthma_slot );
  // same way for others.
}
```

The slots that i have mentioned are just for example, connect it to the slot that you need it to be connected to.

## UPDATE :

Here is a mini-implementation made using just the two buttons :

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
   
class QPushButton;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QPushButton *mAmputationButton;
    QPushButton *mAsthmaButton;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    mAmputationButton( new QPushButton("Amputation" ) ),
    mAsthmaButton( new QPushButton("Astham" ) )
{
    setWindowTitle("First Aid");

    QWidget *sampleWidget = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout();
    lay->addWidget(mAmputationButton);
    connect(mAmputationButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked );
    connect(mAsthmaButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked );
    lay->addWidget(mAsthmaButton);
    sampleWidget->setLayout(lay);
    setCentralWidget(sampleWidget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    QDialog *sampleDialog = new QDialog();
    sampleDialog->setModal(true);
    sampleDialog->show();
}
```

**Note1 :** In the slot `on_pushbutton_clicked`, I am just creating a new dialog and showing it. Just add your slot logic there and you will be good to go.

**Note2 :** It will be advisable to have all your connections in a single method such as `Initialize Connections` as already mentioned above.

Take this mini-implementation just as an example that you can work on top of rather than a copy-paste use of it.

Comment: So sad. :/ I still cannot make it. I tried to get idea from these comments. The QStringList(&amp;quot;amputation&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;asthama&amp;quot;) also showed error and i tried  connect (button, &amp;amp;QPushButton:: released, this, &amp;amp;MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked); at the end of each if statement. But it is also not working. Why is it so? Connecting each button at if else loop may not be a practical way. But, it must work. Isnt it?

Comment: The solutions posted in both answers should work just about fine. What error does it show you ?

Comment: In the above my code, I added if(i=0){
             QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Amputation");
             lay->addWidget(button);
             connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked,this, &MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked);
        } code.Shouldn't it work?

Comment: I also tried qstringlist. It compiles well, but the new window still doesn't open up when pressed.

Comment: Did you try to debug and see what happens ? Does it hit the slot and the window doesn't open or is it an error in the connection being made ?
Another pointer : Try doing it for just one case and then extend it to all your cases.

Comment: @user9251346 : I have added a mini-implementation in the update of my answer. Have a look, and extend it to your huge 25 button implementation.